# MATLAB code on linux server

Tags: linux, matlab

I have a MATLAB code like ( *mycode.m* ) on my laptop in a directory like "*/home/user/apps/mfiles/mycode.m*", and I access to a linux server that MATLAB is installed on it, how can I add the directory of mycode.m to the Linux server Matlab path with a code like addpath('*/home/user/apps/mfiles/mycode.m*') **without copying my *.m file* on linux server**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't do what I wanted in my Question, but with installing *SecPanel* on my ubuntu I could load *Matlab* from server on my laptop screen and write my code easily on it.

```
sudo apt-get install secpanel
```